# va_list type on iOS 64-bit Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, 32bit-64bit, variadic-functions

I have the following code which does not work on the 64-bit iOS Simulator. It crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the following line `[invocation setArgument:args atIndex:index];`

But this code works on all 32-bit and 64-bit iPhone and iPad devices and even on the 32-bit Simulator.

What I found out so far is that the cast to `char*` is probably the source of the error. `va_list` seems to be of `char*` type except on the 64-bit iOS Simulator.

How would I avoid this error? Could this lead to problems on devices?

```
+(NSInvocation*)invocationWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector 

retainArguments:(BOOL)retainArguments, ...;
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, retainArguments);
    char* args = (char*)ap;
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [target methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    if (retainArguments) {
        [invocation retainArguments];
    }
    [invocation setTarget:target];
    [invocation setSelector:aSelector];
    for (int index = 2; index < [signature numberOfArguments]; index++) {
        const char *type = [signature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:index];
        NSUInteger size, align;
        NSGetSizeAndAlignment(type, &size, &align);
        NSUInteger mod = (NSUInteger)args % align;
        if (mod != 0) {
            args += (align - mod);
        }
        [invocation setArgument:args atIndex:index];
        args += size;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return invocation;
}
```

Comment: It crashes deservedly. The author of the code deliberately avoided the standard va_arg macro and reimplemented it himself, badly. You've got a perfect answer, describing exactly how it should have been implemented in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem comes at `args += (align - mod);`, how `va_arg` works is not known, it may be different between two version of compiler. I recommend to use `va_arg` instead of moving the pointer of `args` yourself.

This way you must use Objective-C object as parameters, because we have assumed the type of them is `id`.

```
+ (NSInvocation*)invocationWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector
                      retainArguments:(BOOL)retainArguments, ...
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, retainArguments);
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [target methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    if (retainArguments) {
        [invocation retainArguments];
    }
    [invocation setTarget:target];
    [invocation setSelector:aSelector];
    for (int index = 2; index < [signature numberOfArguments]; index++) {
        id argument = va_arg(ap, id) ;
        [invocation setArgument:&argument atIndex:index];
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return invocation;
}
```

I believe we can do better to use `const char *type = [signature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:index];` and use some method to decode the type which can be passed to `va_arg`, but I didn't find an solution to achieve that.